TypeScript Error: No overload matches this call in Express route handler
I'm working on an Express.js application with TypeScript, and I'm encountering a type error that I can't resolve. Here's the relevant code:
import express from 'express';
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { config } from '../config';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

// ... other code ...

router.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  // Route handler implementation
});

export default router;

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<express.Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application<Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>) => Promise<...>' is missing the following properties from type 'Application<Record<string, any>>': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 63 more.

The error seems to be related to the types of the req and res parameters in the route handler. I've imported Request and Response types from 'express', but the error persists.
Here are my questions:
What's causing this type mismatch?
How can I correctly type the route handler to resolve this error?
Are there any specific TypeScript configurations or type definitions I should be aware of when working with Express?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I've tried and observed:
I imported the Request and Response types from Express and used them to type the route handler parameters.
I expected this to resolve the type mismatch, as these types should be compatible with Express's router methods.
However, the error persists, suggesting that there might be an issue with how the Express types are being interpreted or that there's a mismatch between the Express version and the type definitions being used

I can't reproduce this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?allowUnreachableCode=true&experimentalDecorators=true&target=99#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAUwB5iggzuuAzKERwDkyqG6hA3AFAD0NcokscAyjFMGAjngYeu04JKteo2jwA3nADGEAHbZgAczgBfHviIA6bTTmKVI8c2kAlBAEcArhhgAaOBfSR56bhtxbiKNJhFUBgJweNYwCFBwALyIvmTaZhBhEQAUAJTUonC62nAQMAAWEbIQACbcOVRUoeFQ2pACKYT6aACG4QC0MkUyANZJMB3umMAKhI6t6ACe8jJwKWiWAFxOVrYCjn4rzq7uadEAfHCSVHBwdE4D3AWt8qUANsWMjyAI8jDto-JUahlVJBI4OVsK1rPd4DUIhQgA So I fear that whatever the problem is, we don't have enough info here to figure it out.

You've omitted the code here but from the error you seem to be returning the res object in your handler. Normally in express your route handlers should not be returning this.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

please downgrade the @types/express package to fix this. you can do so by doing npm i -D @types/express@4

This solved it for me, v5 types do not work with Express 4

dont return the res. instead use void return after res.
like
res.status(400).send({ message: 'You are not valid for this website.' });
return;


I do not have the reputation to upvote or comment but @Samiul Karim's answer seems to be the "correct" method going forward without downgrading express/types
Initial
return res.status(200);

Fixed
res.status(200); 
return;


Downgrade the @types/express package- npm i -D @types/express@4
The problem occurs mainly for the latest version.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
